# When one of the boxes has a greater content is one over the another

Tags: html, css

please view image here: http://s18.postimg.org/9tfej2sdl/duvida_stack.png

I have a problem, boxes over the other.
When one of the boxes has a greater content is one over the another.

CSS:

```
    #destaques_container{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#destaques_container_dentro{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    display: inline;
    min-height: 190px; 
    font-family: 'Signika', Arial, Verdana;
    font-size:16px;
}
.box_shadow_preview{ 
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 190px; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    border-width: 1px; 
    border-style: solid; 
    border-color: #DDDDDD; 
    border-radius: 0px; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 16px 0px rgba(52, 84, 109, 0.65);
-moz-box-shadow:    2px 2px 16px 0px rgba(52, 84, 109, 0.65);
box-shadow:         2px 2px 16px 0px rgba(52, 84, 109, 0.65);
-webkit-border-radius: 99px 20px 0px 20px;-moz-border-radius: 99px 20px 0px 20px;border-radius: 99px 20px 0px 20px;
} 
#destaques_line{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #destaques_container{
        width: 1002px;
    }
#destaques_container_dentro{
    width: 46%;
    font-size:16px;
}

.box_shadow_preview{ 
    width: 46%;
} 

}
```

DIV HTML:

```
<div id="destaques_container_dentro">
    <div class="box_shadow_preview">
        <div id="destaques_line">
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<div id="destaques_container_dentro">
    <div class="box_shadow_preview">
        <div id="destaques_line">
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<div id="destaques_container_dentro">
    <div class="box_shadow_preview">
        <div id="destaques_line">
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<div id="destaques_container_dentro">
    <div class="box_shadow_preview">
        <div id="destaques_line">
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Could please help me with any tips that resource use so that when a box has the highest content, the following become more distant as when the box is with the maximum height of 190px.

Comment: make it fixed height and enable the vertical scrool..

Comment: you have duplicate ID's in your HTML which can cause unexpected behaviour

Comment: Are you asking to make the taller (more height) box overlap the shorter one? or to keep them from overlapping at all?

Comment: @whitebeard thanks for the reply, I need the boxes do not overlap. That when a box is higher than the other space between them is maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frequently, it's easier to let the browser decide on placement of things, but with things floating in the browsers window space you may have to make some absolute definitions to help it calculate the best layout.

From your css, it looks like you are trying to be responsive to window size, so defining heights and widths of objects will be helpful.

You have a mixture of floated items, absolute positioning and different display types, as well as multiple items with the same id. This can lead to unpredictable behavior in the browser.

In the code below, I have changed the id's to classes and removed the display and position statements.  Then I made all the boxes have the same  heights and widths, and made them scroll-able.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<link href='testing.css' rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div id="destaques_container">
<div class="destaques_container_dentro">
    <div class="box_shadow_preview">
        <!--Adding div to use as header. Inline styling just to make it more obvious -->
        <div style="width:100%;height:99px;text-align:center;background-color:#ff0;opacity:0.3;">box header</div>
        <!--This div has a unique id.  It has different css. -->
        <div id="destaques_line_1">
             box 1<br /><br /><br />scrollable div with a div above for a header<br />yellow background added to highlight it<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="destaques_container_dentro">
    <div class="box_shadow_preview">
        <div class="destaques_line">
             box 2<br />      <br />       <br />  <br />      <br />
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="destaques_container_dentro">
    <div class="box_shadow_preview">
        <div class="destaques_line">
             box 3<br /><br /><br /><br />scrollable div with left padding<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />box 3<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />box 3<br />
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="destaques_container_dentro">
    <div class="box_shadow_preview">
        <div class="destaques_line">
             box 4<br /><br /><br />     <br /><br />
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
#destaques_container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.destaques_container_dentro{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    /*display: inline;*/
    min-height: 190px; 
    font-family: 'Signika', Arial, Verdana;
    font-size:16px;
    width: 46%;
}
.box_shadow_preview{ 
    /*position: absolute;
    display: block;*/
  width:100%;
    min-height: 190px; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    border-width: 1px; 
    border-style: solid; 
    border-color: #DDDDDD; 
    border-radius: 0px; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 16px 0px rgba(52, 84, 109, 0.65);
-moz-box-shadow:    2px 2px 16px 0px rgba(52, 84, 109, 0.65);
box-shadow:         2px 2px 16px 0px rgba(52, 84, 109, 0.65);
-webkit-border-radius: 99px 20px 0px 20px;-moz-border-radius: 99px 20px 0px 20px;border-radius: 99px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.destaques_line{
    width: 100%;
    height: 190px;
    padding-left:99px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /*display: block;
    clear: both;*/
}enter code here
```

The following is the result:

[image: Screen shot of html/css result]

Given that big, beautiful, rounded corner on the top left of each box, scrolling text will end up displaying outside the borders, so I added a couple of options to consider:

1. Add a div above the scroll-able content.  Use it as a header or show content that should be always visible.
2. Use left padding to push contents away from the rounded corner.

Comment: If the boxes must grow, it would be possible to use absolute positioning and some javascript to position them on document load, page-resize, and if the contents change.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `position: absolute;  display: inline-block;`   from `.box_shadow_preview{`.

Also remove `.box_shadow_preview{ width: 46%; }`.

Overlapping issue will be solved but alignment will break. Use equal height script for making blocks same height.